# Unable to set ImageView content description within function

Tags: android, kotlin, android-imageview

Why doesn't my function allow me to set a content description for my `ImageView`? It seems to allow me to set a drawable resource and text though.

```
class MyAdapter(
    private val dataIVPlayOrPause: Drawable,
    private val dataTVSong: String
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapterEmbark.MyViewHolder>() {

    private val typeHeader = 1
    private val typeItem = 2

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, type: Int): MyViewHolder {
        return when (type) {
            typeHeader -> MyViewHolder(inflateHelper(R.layout.header, parent))

            typeItem -> MyViewHolder(inflateHelper(R.layout.body, parent))

            else -> MyViewHolder(inflateHelper(R.layout.body, parent))
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if (getItemViewType(position) == typeHeader) {

        } else if (getItemViewType(position) == typeItem) {
            val ivPlayPause = viewHolder.itemView. iv_Play_Pause
            ivPlayPause(R.drawable.play)
            ivPlayPause = R.string.play.toString()

            val buttonClickListener = View.OnClickListener {
                if (tvSongName.text == null) {
                    playSong(tvSongName, ivPlayPause)
                } else {
                    pauseSong(tvSongName, ivPlayPause)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun inflateHelper(resId: Int, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        return LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(resId, parent, false)
    }

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return dataTitle.size + 1
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return if (position == 0) typeHeader
        else typeItem
    }

    private fun playSong(
        tvSongName: TextView,
        ivPlayPause: ImageView
    ) {
        tvSongName.text = "Song name"

        ivPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause)

        ivPlayPause.contentDescription = getString(R.string.pause)

    }
}
```

Comment: What does it mean "doesn't allow me"? Is there a compile-time error?

Comment: @GiorgioAntonioli Unresolved reference: 'getString'

Comment: In which class the method `playSong()` is declared into?

Comment: The same class as my `Fragment`

Comment: So, the method `playSong()` is declared INSIDE a class which extends `Fragment`? Can't you post the entire class?

Comment: The class is actually an adapter. Apologies for any confusion. Posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are in a `RecyclerView.Adapter`, you can't access the `Activity`, `Fragment` or `Context` instance in which `getString()` is declared.

In this case you can use the `Context` of your `ImageView` to get the string:

```kotlin
ivPlayPause.contentDescription = ivPlayPause.context.getString(R.string.pause)
```

Comment: Interesting, but now Talkback is reading the content description as a number rather than the word **pause**

Comment: @MacaronLover I think that probably you are still using the reference (which is an int) of the string instead of the resolved one somewhere